# Why does square root of 50 resembles sin(45°)?

Tags: geometry

I was formulating the steps to calculate the area of a fence plank, and was looking at the sloped shape of the top of a plank (beeing a right angle tip).

My example plank had a width of $10$ cm, and the side of the sloped tip got the length

$\sqrt{50}$.

That is $7.071...$

After that I looked at $\sin(45°)$ which is

$0.7071...$

(Even if this story might seem unclear, the numbers are clearly similar)

Is there a connection between these numbers?

Is there a geometric explanation why these numbers are similar (except for a step of the comma)?

The longer versions are

$7.07106781186$

$0.70710678118$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sqrt{50}=\sqrt{2*25}=5\sqrt{2}$

It is known that $\sin 45^o$ is $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ So there's your answer.

Answer (score 5):

The exact value of $\sin(45^{\circ})$ is $\frac{\sqrt 2}2$.

On the other hand, $\sqrt{50} = \sqrt{25}\sqrt{2} = 5\sqrt{2}$.

You can see from these two expressions that $\sqrt{50}$ is exactly 10 times as large as $\sin(45^{\circ})$.

Now, if you want to know why $\sin(45^{\circ}) = \frac{\sqrt 2}2$, draw an isosceles right triangle with legs of length $\sqrt{2}$, and use the Pythagorean Theorem to find the length of the hypotenuse.

Answer (score 4):

Draw a right isosceles triangle, making the sides next to the right angle $\sqrt{50}$ units long. The other two angles will be $45^\circ$ and the longest side (the hypotenuse) will be, as per Pythagoras' theorem:

$$\sqrt{(\sqrt{50})^2+(\sqrt{50})^2}=\sqrt{50+50}=\sqrt{100}=10$$

and now you can see on this triangle that

$$\sin 45^\circ=\frac{\text{opposite side}}{\text{hypotenuse}}=\frac{\sqrt{50}}{10}$$

which explains why $\sin 45^\circ$ and $\sqrt{50}$ have the same digits. (The latter is just $10$ times the former!).